# Unable to login into spotify from Samsung Galaxy Note S20 Ultra

Tags: samsung, android-11, samsung-galaxy-note, spotify

I have recently purchased the Samsung Galaxy Note S20 Ultra.

When I'm trying to login into spotify, then it is giving a message - **Something went wrong, please try again**. I also checked from my other device, i.e, iPhone. I'm able to login from that device.

I tried all the methods like clearing cache, re-installating the app and so on. But the issue still persists.

What is the actual issue ? Is this issue caused due to One UI ? Please help.

Comment: Have you tried exporting the app and try to install apk on another phone? If it does not still work try imstalling other variants from third party websites.

Comment: @Silent The apk is working on another android phone.

Comment: how about going to the previous version of the app? And if it works i suggest usig it until next update.

Comment: @Slient Need to check.